# How to show the lowest values in a dual-y chart if a very large value is there

Tags: angular, google-visualization, column-chart

I have created a column graph using google chart with **month** in x-axis. I have two properties, **amount** and number of **contracts**, which have to place in the Y-axis. So, I changed the column chart to dual-Y chart. Added **series and axes** to the column chart configuration to make it as dual-Y chart. I have 2 values in  amount, one is **500k** and another is just **50**. The problem is, The column for 50 is not displaying.
I have added vAxis.viewWindow.min value. But the chart is not displaying the lowest value.

```
config5 = new ColumnChartConfig('',{
                        0: { axis: 'amount',viewWindow: { min: 50 } }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'contract'.
                        1: { axis: 'contract'} // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'amount'.
                    },
                    {
                        y: {
                        amount: {label:'Amount', // Left y-axis.
                        contract: {side: 'right', label: 'Contract' // Right y-axis.
                        }
                    },{},{},  width, '100%', {
                            height: '100%',
                            width: '100%',
                            top: 0,
                            left: 0,
                            bottom: 0,
                            right: 0
                    });
```

Sample Data

```
[["2019-5-01","0","0"],
["2019-6-01","0","0"],
["2019-7-01","0","0"],
["2019-8-01","0","0"],
["2019-9-01","0","0"],
["2019-10-01","0","0"],
["2019-11-01","0","0"],
["2019-12-01","0","0"],
["2020-1-01","0","0"],
["2020-2-01","0","0"],
["2020-3-01","88","1"],
["2020-4-01","98835","2"]]
```

Drawing Chart

```
data5 = [month,amount,contract]
let array = element;
            array[0] = new Date(array[0]).getMonth() == 0 ? new 
            Date(array[0]).getFullYear().toString() : moment(new 
            Date(array[0])).format("MMM");
            array[1] = parseInt(array[1]);
            array[2] = parseInt(array[2]);
            this.data5.push(array);
```

Here **config5** is the configuration for the chart and the data5, array, which store the data.
In my project the chart is draw by calling a service.

Configuration variable

```
 options = {
        title: title,
        series : series,
        axes: axes,
        hAxis: hAxis,
        vAxis: vAxis,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        chartArea: config.chartArea
  };
```

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data and the code that draws the chart?

Comment: @WhiteHat I have edited the question with sample data. could you please check it

Comment: looking at the data, having values `88` and `98835` on the same axis isn't going to work. the chart would need to be 5 pages tall, or taller, before the scale would be large enough to show both values.

Comment: @WhiteHat okay, I can't  increase the height of this graph.

Comment: @WhiteHat whether it is possible to display 88, when the mouse hover over the ''2020-3-01''

Comment: see the `onmouseover` [event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#events)

Comment: @WhiteHat whether it is possible to show a single popup for multiple axes in a dual-Y chart?
Any possibility for displaying the lowest value.